# Replace bar charts in a figure with text for each Y variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a figure that was initially a bar chart. I replaced the values with text in the middle. I want the text to be aligned left inside the graph for each Y value.

[image]

There is also a middle line appearing for some reason.. I have tried to remove the xbar, but that made things worse.. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] 
\caption{Peer comparison between SBP and SARD}
\label{Figure.Top8AMDpeers.SBPvsSARD}
\centering 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \caption{Top 8 AMD peers by SBP} \label{fig:M1} 
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
[
width=6.5cm, height=10cm, y dir = reverse,
symbolic y coords={first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight},
point meta=explicit symbolic,
ytick=data,
xmajorticks=false,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal \pgfplotspointmeta}]
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\DataX} \pgfplotspointmeta},
\addplot[xbar,fill={rgb:red,0;green,47;blue,135}] coordinates 
{
(0,first) [peer 1]
(0,second) [peer 2]
(0,third) [peer3]
(0,forth) [peer 4]
(0,fifth) [peer 5]
(0,sixth) [peer 6]
(0,seventh) [peer 7]
(0,eight) [peer 8]
}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

The line you see in the middle is actually the `xbar` itself. All the bars have length zero, so you end up with the outline of zero-width rectangles, which is a line. You could add `draw=none` to the `\addplot` options to remove it, but might as well use just `\addplot[]`.

Next, use `nodes near coords align=right`, not `nodes near coords align={horizontal \pgfplotspointmeta}`. The alignment shouldn't depend in any way of the meta value (in your case "peer 1", "peer 2" etc.). With the `right` setting, you end up with these nodes being placed right of the end of the corresponding x-coordinate. And because the all the x-coordinates are zero, that means the nodes are placed right of x = 0. Hence, to move them to the left side of the axis, set the x-limits of the axis with `xmin=0,xmax=1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \caption{Top 8 AMD peers by SBP} \label{fig:M1} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}
[
width=6.5cm, height=10cm, y dir = reverse,
symbolic y coords={first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight},
point meta=explicit symbolic,
ytick=data,
xmajorticks=false,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=right, % <-- modified
xmin=0,xmax=1 % <-- added
]

\addplot[] % <-- overwrite default settings with no settings
 coordinates 
{
(0,first) [peer 1]
(0,second) [peer 2]
(0,third) [peer3]
(0,forth) [peer 4]
(0,fifth) [peer 5]
(0,sixth) [peer 6]
(0,seventh) [peer 7]
(0,eight) [peer 8]
}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the additional explanations which you offered. Now I understand a bit more how this works!